# Q&A functionality with a plugin?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I want to know whether someone knows of some plugin which can insert question answer functionaily just like [MakeUseof](http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/)?
I want this functiolity in an existing site, not some standalone theme floating around in the market. Or any detailed explaination how with multiple plugins this can be acheieved.
I want much simmillar facility as on the makeuse of site. With tabs like most popular, unanswered etc.

Answer (score 2):

there are [a lot of plugins out there](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=question) to add this kind of functionality and
the one that i would recommend is [Question and Answer Forum](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/question-and-answer-forum/)
which will get you closes to the example you link with no hard work.

**main features:**

- ask question form short code
- list question short code
- email admin when question is asked capability
- custom email to author of question when question is asked
- display of questions can be customised by theme
- spam filtering of questions
- dashboard widget showing last 5 questions
- user profiles including a tables with the number of questions, answers and best answers they have provided.
- best answers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Pubble. Pubble is a [real-time Q&A plugin](http://www.pubble.co) that lives on websites, blogs & Facebook pages to crowdsource the best FAQ's for anything. With Pubble you add a code snippet to the pages that you want to enable Q&A on. The Q&A's from across your site are then aggregated into a killer FAQ page that looks like:

Threaded Layout (similar to MakeUseof)

[image: Pubble Threaded layout]

Tiled Layout (pinterest'esque style)

[image: Pubble tiled layout]

The [Pubble WordPress Q&A Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pubble-social-qa/) includes the following features:

1. Answer prompt for previously answered questions, which reduces repetitive questions and delivers instant answers to your visitors.
2. Facebook Q&A app. that works with your web site. Questions asked on Facebook show on your FAQ page. Answers are also prompted into Facebook.
3. Full configuration options (moderation, custom themes, community management, etc.)
4. Easy setup. Just create your account, grab your code and add to your site.
5. Speech input for question submission (Chrome browser only)

Hope this helps.